# What are our options for dealing with a buggy Windows 10 on-screen keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

For years my partner has used her Asus Padfone X as her main computing device.  But it's getting old, and manufacturer's have left that niche market untouched by new devices, so we decided to move her to a convertible laptop.  We chose the Lenova Yoga, mostly for the SSD, dedicated graphics, and large 4k screen in a reasonable pricepoint.  Our hope was to have the Lenova work as closely as possible like the Android tablet did.

The primary use of this device is web browsing, with potential future gaming in mind.  These problems have all occurred while browsing the web.

**The Problem**

So far the laptop has proven virtually unusable.  With the most recent Windows 10 update the keyboard does now support slide.  However, it becomes buggy on a regular  basis (after a few minutes of use):

- Slide simply stops working.  All the settings are still correct.  Hiding/showing the keyboard doesn't help.  Changing the settings and then changing them back doesn't help.  Closing the browser and reopening doesn't help.  Only restarting the computer fixes it.
- Cursor cannot be placed anywhere in the focused input.  Tapping in the input just leaves the cursor at the start and any keystrokes are appended to the end of what has already been typed, meaning you can't correct any of slide's constant mistakes without deleting everything after and retyping.  Again, none of the above troubleshooting steps helps.
- Sometimes the keyboard doesn't show at all.  Tapping the input constantly, or sometimes rotating the screen or converting the laptop, is required to fix it.
- Sometimes, especially with the cursor issue (point 2 above), the entirely laptop simply stops responding to screen taps.

**Solution**

I know next to nothing about Windows 10, nor its tablet functions.  Applying my generic tech knowledge I've come up with the following likely solutions:

- Some keyboard setting, or Windows setting or registry entry, needs corrected
- The keyboard needs reinstalled somehow
- An alternative keyboard app needs installed (is that even possible?)
- Windows need reinstalled
- The laptop needs returned and we need to buy an Android tablet because this is just the way Windows 10 is

I'm unsure how to begin tracking down the problem, let alone choosing a solution.  What are our options for dealing with this buggy Windows 10 on-screen keyboard?

Comment: What is this slide?

Comment: @harrymc Slide is an option popularized on phones that allows you to slide your finger in one motion across each letter in a word instead of having to tap on each one.  For many people it's far faster and easier than typing.

Comment: I've also heard it called swipe or glide; it's possible slide is a regional thing.

Comment: It's called swipe on Windows. See if you are really using the swipe keyboard ([link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-touch-keyboard-windows-10)), and also check [this setting](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/full-layout-touch-keyboard-windows-10).

Comment: @harrymc Yes, thank you.  Those are actually the same articles I came across and followed when trying to enable it, after finally realizing it required a Windows update.

Comment: The swipe keyboard is new to Windows 10 v1803,  so might be buggy. Check if your display driver has an update.